# How do I pad 1 ns to all the duplicated DatetimeIndex in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How do I pad 1 ns to all the duplicated `DatetimeIndex` in a `Pandas DataFrame`?

for example, from this:

```
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989120
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989120
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989120
2016-11-13 20:00:10.123945353
2016-11-13 20:00:14.565989314
2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989315
2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989315
2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989315
```

to this:

```
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989120
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989121
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989122
2016-11-13 20:00:10.123945353
2016-11-13 20:00:14.565989314
2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989315
2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989316
2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989317
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with convert [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
print (df.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989120    0
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989120    1
2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989120    2
2016-11-13 20:00:10.123945353    0
2016-11-13 20:00:14.565989314    0
2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989315    0
2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989315    1
2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989315    2
dtype: int64

df.index = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989120',
               '2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989121',
               '2016-11-13 20:00:10.617989122',
               '2016-11-13 20:00:10.123945353',
               '2016-11-13 20:00:14.565989314',
               '2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989315',
               '2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989316',
               '2016-11-13 20:00:18.565989317'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: arr i was using cumsum to try to get the same result and it doesnt work of course.. i didnt know cumcount() Thank you!!